# Display in a graph just unique values for a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Report table with the fallowing columns: `id, project_id, key_id, position, created_at`.

And the fallowing code, which is going to populate a graph, the code that I have now, is working good, but the problem that I'm facing is that a `key_id` has multiple positions, and I only want to count a `key_id` with 3 positions (for example), once. I tried using `distinct` but it didn't work.

Thank you

```
def self.chart_data(start = 1.weeks.ago, current_user)
   positions = where("position <=  50").position_by_day(start, current_user)
   (start.to_date..Date.today).map do |date|
   {
      created_at: date,  
      position: positions[date] || 0,
    }                    
 end                    
end                      

def self.position_by_day(start, current_user)
    user_projects = Project.where(user_id: current_user.id).first
    results = user_projects.reports.where(created_at:   start.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now)
    results = results.group("date(created_at)")
    results = results.select("date(created_at) as created_at, count(*) as count")
    results.each_with_object({}) do |result, possitions|
      possitions[result.created_at.to_date] = result.count
    end                  
end
```

Also to get all the 'keys' that a user can have, I need to get all the `projects` for a user, and then get all the `keys` through a loop on each project. How can I do this? Can I wrap the `results` in a loop? Or is it a better way?

Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user will send all the projects to this method:

```
def self.position_by_day(start) 
   report = where(created_at: start.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now)
   report = report.group("date(created_at)").group(:key_id)
   report = report.select("date(created_at) as created_at, count(*) as count, key_id")
   result = report.count.inject ({}) do |hash, keydata|
     hash[keydata[0][0]] ||= 0
     hash[keydata[0][0]] += 1
     hash                 
   end                    
   return result          
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use group to filter on distinct attributes

```
def self.chart_data(start = 1.weeks.ago, current_user)
   positions = where("position <=  50").group('key_id, date(created_at)').position_by_day(start, current_user)
   (start.to_date..Date.today).map do |date|
   {
      created_at: date,  
      position: positions[date] || 0,
    }                    
 end                    
end
```

Some caveats though. It wouldn't work with a postgres database. And I can't say which of those grouped objects will be returned, that might not be an issue, or you would have to control it with group-wise maximum selection in your sql.

And for the associated keys, you can include associated objects in the query like this:

```
User.all(:conditions => {id: current_user.id}, :include => :keys)
```

Comment: Position is a column in a table, can you perform a select on a column?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood. No, that wouldn't be possible. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I tried already this and is still not working. I get 1 key instead of 19, and currently I get 24 keys.

Comment: That's weird, I created a model with some dummy data, and Report.all.map(&:position) gives me  => ["10", "30", "50", "52", "32", "323", "3233", "32333"] while Report.all.group(:key_id).map(&:position) outputs  => ["50", "32", "32333"]. What does the generated sql outputted in the logs look like?

Comment: With you code
`GROUP BY key_id, date(created_at)  [["project_id", 1]]`
With my code
`Report Load (0.5ms)  SELECT date(created_at) as created_at, count(*) as count FROM "reports" WHERE "reports"."project_id" = $1 AND "reports"."competitor_id" IS NULL AND (possition <= 50) AND ("reports"."created_at" BETWEEN '2013-11-01 00:00:00.000000' AND '2013-11-08 15:35:10.507421') GROUP BY date(created_at)  [["project_id", 1]]`

Comment: Ok, so with you code your get 24 keys because you got 24 distinct dates in created_at (which is the column you are grouping by), try adding key_id to the group clause. group('key_id, date(created_at)'), also in my updated answer.

Comment: Still not working, i still get 1 key, thank you for your help.